# LWJGL and Texture Loading - Seems to create a new object at every frame

Tags: textures, lwjgl

So I have just started out with LWJGL and I'm trying to create a simple 2D platform game. The problem I'm arguing with at the moment is the texture loading. The Problem is that everything works really neat as long as I keep all the texture loading related methods in the class of the main method.

As soon as I move it into a separate class `TextureHandler` it wont work, only if I add the `loadTexture()` method into the `drawTexture()` method. The problem then is that it keeps  making new objects every frame as far as I can tell. I have Google'd for hours but cant for the life of me find a solution.

**Main class:**

```
public class Main {
    String playerPath = "res/PlayerNeutral.png";

    public void render() {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void initGL() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.create();
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Initiating OpenGL
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Enables the Alpha Blending
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    public void start() {
        initGL();

        TextureHandler.loadTexture(Player.playerText, playerPath);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            render();
            TextureHandler.drawTexture(Player.playerText, playerPath);          
            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main test = new Main();
        test.start();
    }
```

**TextureHandler class:**

```
public class TextureHandler {
    public static void textRelease(Texture text){
        text.release();
    }

    public static void loadTexture(Texture texture, String path){
        try {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));

            System.out.println("Texture loaded: "+texture);
            System.out.println(">> Image width: "+texture.getImageWidth());
            System.out.println(">> Image height: "+texture.getImageHeight());
            System.out.println(">> Texture width: "+texture.getTextureWidth());
            System.out.println(">> Texture height: "+texture.getTextureHeight());
            System.out.println(">> Texture ID: "+texture.getTextureID());

            TextureImpl.unbind();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void drawTexture(Texture texture, String path) {
        try {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));

            System.out.println("Texture loaded: "+texture);
            System.out.println(">> Image width: "+texture.getImageWidth());
            System.out.println(">> Image height: "+texture.getImageHeight());
            System.out.println(">> Texture width: "+texture.getTextureWidth());
            System.out.println(">> Texture height: "+texture.getTextureHeight());
            System.out.println(">> Texture ID: "+texture.getTextureID());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Color.white.bind();
        texture.bind();

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(), 100);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(), 100+texture.getTextureHeight());
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100 + texture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glEnd();

        texture.release();
    }
}
```

**Player class:**

```
public class Player {
    private int x;//x pos on screen
    private int y;//y pos on screen
    public static Texture playerText;

    // method for moving the player object around
    public void move() {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT))
            x++;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT))
            x--;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP))
            y++;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN))
            y--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in your `drawTexture()` method you do the following.

```
try {
    texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));

    System.out.println("Texture loaded: "+texture);
    System.out.println(">> Image width: "+texture.getImageWidth());
    System.out.println(">> Image height: "+texture.getImageHeight());
    System.out.println(">> Texture width: "+texture.getTextureWidth());
    System.out.println(">> Texture height: "+texture.getTextureHeight());
    System.out.println(">> Texture ID: "+texture.getTextureID());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Simply remove the above code from your `drawTexture()` method.

The texture still gets loaded, because you already did that once by calling your `loadTexture()` method, before you enter your rendering loop.

## Edit

> I'm pretty sure I've already tried that. I do want to remember I put it in there because it wouldn't work without it, a "quick fix" if you will.

As you said that I just realized something. Your `loadTexture()` method is way off. That is probably because you don't know you can't do something like that.

References are passed by value in Java. What that means is that, when you pass a variable through a method, the variable is then a local variable of the method. Thereby changing the variable inside the method won't change the original variable.

### Example

I hope you will understand the following example. If you want to assign something new to a variable, you can't do it using the variable passed through the method. You need to return it and then assign it.

```
public class PassingVariables {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello World!";

        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Hello World!

        test1(s);

        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Hello World!

        s = test2(s);

        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Testing...

        s = test3(s);

        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Hello World!
    }

    private static String test1(String s) {
        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Hello World!

        s = "Testing...";

        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Testing...
    }

    private static String test2(String s) {
        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Hello World!

        return "Testing...";
    }

    private static String test3(String s) {
        System.out.println(s); // Prints | Testing...

        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

## New Code

Here is your code where I've changed some of the things so it will work when we take the above in mind.

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String path) {
    Texture texture = null;

    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path));

        /* Removed all your println to spare some lines in the answer */

        TextureImpl.unbind();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return texture;
}

public static void drawTexture(Texture texture) {
    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(), 100);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100+texture.getTextureWidth(), 100+texture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100 + texture.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();

    /* 
     * I don't recognize the release() method, but if it deletes the texture
     * then remove if. If it simply unbinds the texture then keep it. If it
     * does remove it, then change it to something like unbind(), if such
     * method exist.
     */
    texture.release();
}

public void start() {
    initGL();

    Player.playerText = TextureHandler.loadTexture(playerPath);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        render();
        TextureHandler.drawTexture(Player.playerText, playerPath);          
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();      
}
```

Comment: Will try this when I get home but im pretty sure I've allready tried that. I do want to remember I put it in there because it wouldnt work without it, a "quick fix" if you will :)

Comment: @user2966263 I just realized something when you said that, I took a look at your code and found what your talking about, look at my edited answer. :)

Comment: Wow, I can't belive I actually have missed that in Java... Big thanks tho! Very clear description and nice to not be handed a "copy -> paste" wihtout explanation, actually understands what was wrong. would upvote if I could (new member..)!

Comment: @Bambuh You can always mark the correct answer to your own question, if you think my answer, answers your question then you could always mark mine as the correct one. But anyways you're welcome buddy! :)

Comment: ah, as I mentioned. new member :) fixed and sorted